# Is there a way to find the standard deviation for data in two separate csv files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, standard-deviation

I've created 2 programs that clean weather data and simplify it into csv files. Is there a way I can take this information and find the standard deviation of them?

I've imported one csv but am just stuck. I'm new to this

Comment: post your code.

Comment: Yes. Provide data in csv files.